# AWS python web app with database sample

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I have my AWS python (flask) app running, but I'm struggling with a connection to a database. I've been looking around for some days now for a good step-by-step tutorial or code bases, but haven't found one.  what is the easiest way to get a webapp running including a database? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a NoSql document oriented DB works for you, it's pretty easy to get MongoDB running on AWS and accessing it through pymongo.

The AWS specific quickstart is here:

```
https://wiki.10gen.com/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2+Quickstart
```

and a general Mongodb tutorial is here:

```
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/
```

A PyMongo tutorial is:

```
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to deploy your application to Elastic Beanstalk. Amazon article: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html will help you.

What about database I prefere to create RDS instance, deploy application schema. Than put connection string to db as environment variable to beanstalk. It assumed that you application is getting connection string from environment variable.

Let me know if you have ny questions.

Comment: Hmm, I can't get mysql-python running. Is this doc up to date? Any other more elaborate tutorials or alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty wide open, it really depends on what sort of backend you would like to run. Recently I have been working on a  server-less app using static S3 files to communicate with API Gateway to Lambda, to RDS using SQL Alchemy.

I have used Aurora Mysql but SQLAlchemy allows for the use of several different drivers.

For a NoSQL type I would recommend dynamoDB. I only recommend it because if your app is already on AWS you can streamline concurrency and scale by using their products front to back. I recommend starting to do research on what sort of backend works great for you, once you get the flavor down, look for the best supported and wellknown services that would be a great fit for your app.

I would follow the step by step tutorials in either SQLAlchemy or here for [DynamoDB](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html)

[SQLAlchemy](https://www.pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/) is a great place to go if you want to go the RDS route

Python [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will allow you to use any AWS Service to include DynamoDB